# Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15ITL6 - RAM upgrade and black screen after - too much RAM?

Tags: memory, upgrade, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo laptop with 4GB RAM (soldered to the motherboard) and wanted to upgrade the RAM which can be upgraded up to 12GB RAM if I read the specifications on the Lenovo website. I was on the crucial website and it says I can upgrade to maximum memory: 16GB or 20GB. I bought a 16GB RAM but after upgrading the RAM and restarting my laptop, I have a black screen. Is it because I upgraded to 16GB RAM when I can in fact upgrade up to 12GB or it has nothing to do with it ? Thanks.

Comment: Just a note: Even when systems are capable of handling *more* or *other* memory than originally advised from the manufacturer, i'd not go for it. I've seen systems doing that, running perfect for years but then having all kind of strange issues because of it. Besides that, you could test if the memory you bought has a problem using memtest: https://www.memtest86.com

Comment: thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to be because you upgraded to 16GB instead of 12GB. Normally [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/ideapad-3-15itl6) is reliable. And people on the internet confirm that 20GB total works. Maybe you bought the wrong kind of RAM? Which RAM did you buy exactly?

If this random reddit user is to be believed it should work fine: https://www.reddit.com/r/Lenovo/comments/ozj4dq/ideapad_3_ram_upgrade_limitation/

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Laptops/RAM-and-SSD-upgrade-for-Ideapad-3-15ITL6/m-p/5217992

The [specs](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/IdeaPad/IdeaPad_3_15ITL6/IdeaPad_3_15ITL6_Spec.pdf) say:
Max Memory**

- Up to 12GB (4GB soldered + 8GB SO-DIMM) DDR4-3200 offering•
- Up to 16GB (8GB soldered + 8GB SO-DIMM) DDR4-3200 offering

Notes:
The max memory is based on the test results with current Lenovo® memory offerings. The system may support more
memory as the technology develops.

Comment: Thabks for your reply @Gantendo
this is the RAM I bought. 
https://www.emag.ro/memorie-laptop-crucial-16gb-ddr4-3200mhz-cl22-ct16g4sfra32a/pd/DX1LP9MBM/
these are the specs:
CARACTERISTICI GENERALE
Tip memorie DDR4
Capacitate stocare 16 GB
Numar module 1 x 16GB
Configuratie Single Channel
SPECIFICATII TEHNICE
Frecventa 3200 MHz
Standarde PC4-25600
Format SODIMM
Latenta CAS CL22
Voltaj 1.2 V
Culoare Verde

so I am a bit lost; and I cannot test the RAM I bought for the moment and I run Linux.